# Add a link to Magento Admin for the Media Library

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, configuration

I would like to add a link to the CMS menu on the Magento Admin panel for the Media Library, just under the polls link.

[image]

to link to...

[image]

I tried creating a module with the below **adminhtml.xml**

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <cms>
            <children>
                <medialink translate="title" module="cms">
                    <title>Media Library</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images</action>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                </medialink>
            </children>
        </cms>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <cms>
                        <children>
                            <medialink translate="title">
                                <title>Media Library</title>
                            </medialink>
                        </children>
                    </cms>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

This only succeeds in adding the link to the menu, the `<action>adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images</action>` does not work as I'd hoped.  The link directs the user to a broken page, not the proper media library.

[image]

### UPDATE

Looking more closely at the ajax calls in the browser when you open the media library I see `MediabrowserUtility.openDialog` is called from */js/mage/adminhtml/browser.js*.  Although *browser.js* is not loaded on the dashboard.

Comment: i think you have to load it via ajax somehow. This would be an awesome addition to magento1! I had to explain so many customers how to just add an image to the media library and it's so over complicated that many customers don't get it. I will look into this when I find the time

Comment: There's an extension lanot file manager that does pretty much what you ask.

Comment: @DavidVerholen, thanks.  I had a closer look as to how the media library is being loaded.  See my update.  Not sure how to add this to a module though

Answer (score 4):

The action you are trying to point to is meant to be called via ajax.
If you take a look at the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_Wysiwyg_ImagesController::indexAction()` you will find this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');

    try {
        Mage::helper('cms/wysiwyg_images')->getCurrentPath();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    $this->_initAction()->loadLayout('overlay_popup');
    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('wysiwyg_images.js');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setStoreId($storeId);
    }
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

The line `$this->_initAction()->loadLayout('overlay_popup');`  means that the default layout handle is not loaded. Instead `overly_popup` layout handle is loaded. That's why you get the "broken" page.

Maybe you should create a custom controller action that calls the page you need via ajax. This should solve your problem.